# mongodb refusing connection in python

Tags: python, mongodb

I am using `windows8`, for writing code I use `IDLE`. I tried to connect `python` to `mongodb`. But when trying to get collection name than it gives an error.

> ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:20101: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

This is code for which i am getting an error.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
connection = MongoClient('localhost',20101)
db = connection['Bhautik']
collection = db['Student']
db.collection_names(include_system_collections=True)
```

Comment: The default mongodb server port is 27017. Are you sure that it is really running on 20101?

Comment: using what command did you start your mongod connection

Comment: I tried with port no. 27017. But same error got.

Comment: i started connection with "net start mongod" but its also giving error like service name is invalid.

Comment: I get the same error message and I used default port 27017.  
from pymongo import MongoClient
    client = MongoClient('localhost:27017')
    db = client[db_name]

Answer (score 2):

By the output message you probably didn't set your mongo `bind_ip` or didn't set the `dbpath`. Try this:

```
mongod --dbpath <database_path> --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --port 20101
```

It would be more helpful to put alongside with your code some information regarding the mongodb configuration, like the server port, if you are using authentication or not, which dbpath you are using and so on.

So put in your question your mongodb.conf (if you are using one) or the command you are using to start the mongo server.

Answer (score 2):

If you are starting to use mongoDB after installation, make `C:/data/db` because it is a default database directory which mongoDB uses.

To change the database directory, do type below:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.x\bin> mongod --dbpath "c:\custom_folder"
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem and your solution worked with me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try
run mongo like that:

```
"C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\3.6\\bin\\mongod.exe" --dbpath E:\\data\\db --port 27017 --bind_ip 127.0.0.1
```

E:\data\db should be your location path
then in you code
it will lok like

```
client = MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017)
db = client['addsome']

datas = db.follow_up
```

and if you want to access from a distant machine make sure you open the port "27017" in the firewall

Answer (score 0):

Some times it's gives this error when you forgot to run the local server (if it's run with local server).

To run it you need to write on your terminal:

```
mongod
```

or, if MongoDB not in PATH, you can find it via this link in your computer:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to run MongoDB,

- You should have installed MongoDB into your OS, download it from https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community?tck=docs_server
- Add the installation's bin folder to your system environment variables.
- Openup the terminal and check 'mongod' and 'mongo' commands are working.
- Then try to rerun your python script.