# Python - Cannot connect Python to MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using Python 3.4 the latest version of MongoDB and already installed pymongo using

```
pip install pymongo
```

When I run this .py file

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

if __name__ == "__main__":
    con = MongoClient()

    db = con.test_database

    people = db.people

    people.insert({'name':'Mike', 'food':'cheese'})
    people.insert({'name':'John', 'food':'ham', 'location':'UK'})
    people.insert({'name':'Michelle', 'food':'cheese'})

    peeps = people.find()

    print("INSERT & FIND TEST")
    for person in peeps:
        print(person)
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Alberto/Documents/Python/Kivy/Code/testmongo.py", line 10,     in <module>
people.insert({'name':'Mike', 'food':'cheese'})
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 2197, in insert
with self._socket_for_writes() as sock_info:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 712, in _get_socket
server = self._get_topology().select_server(selector)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 142, in select_server
address))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 118, in select_servers
self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongodb refusing connection in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754757/mongodb-refusing-connection-in-python)

Comment: check mongodb log in '/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log'

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Local Mongodb

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://<yourUsername>:<yourPassword>@<IPAddress>:27017/<yourDB>?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
```

If you are using Atlas Mongodb

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb+srv://<yourUsername>:<yourPassword>@<YourCluster>.mongodb.net/<yourDB>?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
```

Answer (score -2):

Just try to replace the connection with the following line.

```
con = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
```

It works fine for me.