# How to connect Mongo DB from django?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am trying to connect mongodb from django.which is settings.py.
In setting.py i gievrn connection like

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
    }
}
```

Where i am executing command like: python manage.py makemigrations

it is throwing error like

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

Please tell me how to connect Mongodb from django.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your django 2.0 or more with MongoDB database:

Firstly, Install mongoengine for django 2.0

> pip install -e git+https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine.git#egg=django-mongoengine`

And then Add these in your settings file:

```
from mongoengine import *

'django_mongoengine', // Add this line to installed app

MONGODB_DATABASES = {
"default": {
"name": '<db_name>',
"host": 'localhost',
"password": '',
"username": '',
"tz_aware": True, # if you using timezones in django (USE_TZ = True)
},
}
```

You can find the details for querying the database [here](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks @AzyCrw4282, but i am using python 3.0

Comment: That shouldnt be a problem i dont think?

Comment: Hi @AzyCrw4282, can you know what is error like pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. If you please help me to slove this.Thanks.

Comment: CAn you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754757/mongodb-refusing-connection-in-python) plz

Answer (score 0):

Djongo library will be helpfull for this.

https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/

https://pypi.org/project/djongo/

Install djongo
pip3 install djongo

Into settings.py file of your project, add

```
DATABASES = 

    {
         'default': {
             'ENGINE': 'djongo',
             'NAME': 'your-db-name',
         }
    }
```

manage.py makemigrations
manage.py migrate

Comment: Thanks #Deepak M.S.But , i insatll already djongo .but Error is throwing.

Comment: Hi Deepak M.S ,as you said i done with that,But, now error was thrwing like   pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: Use engine as djongo not django

Comment: {
         'default': {
             'ENGINE': 'djongo',
             'NAME': 'your-db-name',
         }
    }